# Java - log in, store users in database

Tags: java, database, forms, authentication

i have problem with the development of user interface in my web application.

**The plan is:**

1. User write his username and password in login form and submit.
2. The request comes to login servlet.
3. Servlet looks to the database for that user and check pass etc..

I know about SSL, form based authentication, checking roles and storing users in DD web.xml.

But i need to store lots of users in database because of automation of creating. Is there any simple solution?

Comment: What's the question exactly? The plan in your question looks fine to solve the problem you have.

Comment: You are just mentioning, what do you want to do. People here are not interested in knowing what you want to do. I might be asking too much, but can you please specify what have you tried so far and what are the hurdles you are facing to get it done.

Comment: Im sorry guys. I just want to know if is there any created system to do that, which can i use instead of creating the new one.

Comment: You can start with some CMS (Content Management System), like Joomla, Drupal, etc. These are already built Systems including the functionality you are looking for. It might help you.

Comment: I need it to build my app, on green meadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [spring-security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/reference.html) or app server proprietary ways of authenticating users stored in a database (like Tomcat's [JDBCRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm)).

But frankly, if you know nothing about spring-security or even spring, and want to avoid proprietary solutions, writing your own servlet filter which goes to the database is quite an easy solution.

Comment: Thank you man! i think that JDBCRealm is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think here can be any better way.

Answer (score 0):

you may choose to create a user in the database - and let the database do the authentication.